# What is the correct syntax for launching ipython qtconsole/notebook for python version=x

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ipython, anaconda

What is the closest thing I can get to a correct **single-line syntax** for launching a specific ipython with the latest anaconda version on Microsoft Windows?

Examples (that don't work):

`C:\> ipython qtconsole --python=3` for the latest version of python 3.

`C:\> ipython notebook --python=3.3.5` for the exact version of python 3.

`C:\> ipython console --log-level=DEBUG --python=3.4` for the exact version of python 3.4 with verbose log

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer on a fresh anaconda install on windows is to use `cmd.exe` and create a new environment:

```
C:\Anaconda>conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda
```

Anaconda fetches, extracts and links the package(s), and provides the helpful message:

```
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate py3k
#
```

To which the user should type:

```
C:\Anaconda>activate py3k
```

hereby `cmd.exe` prints:

```
Activating environment "py3k"...
[py3k] C:\Anaconda>
```

To launch the python qtconsole based on the version declared in the line: `C:\Anaconda>conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda` the user should type:

```
[py3k] C:\Anaconda>ipython qtconsole
```

In case the user still sees python 2.7.6 it will be because s/he/it forgot to add anaconda at the end of the environment creation: C:\Anaconda>conda create -n py3k python=3 ***anaconda***

If a full anaconda environment is not needed, the user may initiate the needed packages only by issuing the command:

```
C:\Anaconda>conda create -n [name] python=[version] python=[version] [list of packages separated by spaces]
```

Thanks to the iPython mailing list for these inputs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `ipython` command doesn't provide a way to choose the python version. 
However you can use the standard python facility for launching modules:

```
pythonX.Y -m IPython <other options>
```

For example:

```
python3 -m IPython qtconsole 
python3.3.5 -m IPython notebook
python3.4 -m IPython console --log-level=DEBUG
```

Instead of asking `ipython` to choose an interpreter you specify the interpreter explicitly and tell it to run the `IPython` installed for it.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake in the formulation of the question. Let me clarify: single line syntax is from cmd.exe

Comment: @BHM A know that, and I don't see what's wrong with what I have written. Inside the command prompt instead of using `ipython` use `python -m IPython`. You may need to update your `PATH` to be able to launch the interpreters, but that's an other matter.

Comment: I guess it requires that you have python version X installed first. If a newbie takes the lastest anaconda installer and simply wants to launch ipython qtconsole with py version X to complete a tutorial, then I guess he will be disappointed as the response will be (`python3` is not recognized as an ... command, ...). If you run `ipython help` you will see what I intend.

Comment: @BHM That's a problem with the environment. When you install python you should add the executable to the `PATH` to fix that error. There's already plently of question about changing environmental variables around. Or did you prefer that I simply answered "you can't do that because it isn't supported by the `ipython` launcher, period."? Your options are use the `-m` switch or nothing.

Comment: The final sentence is the answer I feared would be the only option. I leave the post open for creative hacks, but otherwise you get the cudos in 48 hrs :-)